# Performance of JOIN operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets suppose I have two huge tables

- users(user_id, name, country)
- location(id, user_id, country, city)

If i want to fetch for particular country

1.

```
select * from users u
inner join location l on u.user_id = l.user_id 
where l.country = 'heaven'
```

2.

```
select * from users u
inner join location l on u.user_id = l.user_id 
where u.country = 'heaven'
```

3.

```
select * from users u
inner join location l on u.user_id = l.user_id
where u.country = 'heaven' and l.country = 'heaven'
```

Which of the three would be better approach?
and suppose the result of filtering data by country would be

1. users table has 1000 record with country='heaven'
2. location table has 2 record with country='heaven'

What will be performance now?

Comment: The only real answer is to plan and profile all 3 queries and find out. I don't think it's fruitful for readers to speculate about what the query optimiser might or might not do.

Comment: @no_name_   . . . Your queries do different things.  You should use the query that does what you need.

Comment: for a particular user_id country will always be same.

Comment: @no_name_ . . . That is unlikely.  There are 1000 users in "heaven" according to one table.  At most two according to the other -- well, unless `user_id` is repeated in `users`, which would be just a sign of very bad naming conventions or a lousy data model.

Comment: No i am using the above table for just example

Comment: @no_name_ Don't store the same data into different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries would only return the same results, if one of the following is true:

- `location` records did not exist for all users.
- `users` has duplicate `user_id`s.

It is unclear which.  And, having `country` in both tables suggests that something is wrong with your data model.

That said, if you need both filtering by the `join` and filtering on the country, I would recommend:

```
select *
from users u join
     locations l
     on u.user_id = l.user_id
where l.country = 'heaven';
```

And you want an index on `locations(country, user_id)`.  This should find the two records in `locations` and look up the corresponding values in `users`.  That seems like the fastest way to do what you want.